# Ck editor appendTo not working

Tags: ckeditor, appendto

I am working with ckeditor 3.6.2 , everything works fine just i am not able to append anything to editor, here is my code

```
        CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'post_content','<pre class="html"></pre>' );
```

it does not gives me any error on firebug console but also it's not appending anything to the textarea, tried looking it on ckeditor documentation but none of them solved my problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got it and i was doing it wrong... if anyone else has the same problem try this code

```
        CKEDITOR.instances.post_content.insertText('<pre class="html"></pre>');
```

post_content is the id of your editor